# Postgresql group by for many columns

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by

I have such query:

```
SELECT "Movie"."title", 
       "Movie"."id", 
       "Movie"."publicationDate", 
       "Movie"."authorID", 
       "Author"."photoURL" as "authorPhoto", 
       concat("Author"."name", ' ', "Author"."surname") as "authorName",
       "Movie"."seriesID", 
       "Series"."name" as "seriesName", 
       "Series"."logoURL" as "seriesLogo", 
       "Movie"."languageID" as "language", 
       "Movie"."ratingUp", 
       "Movie"."ratingDown", 
       "userWatched"."watchedDate", 
       CASE WHEN "UserMovieFavourited"."userID" = '6F9BD058-853F-4B50-92D6-9170118A2727' 
            THEN TRUE 
            ELSE FALSE 
            END as "favourited", 
       CASE WHEN "UserMovieWatchlist"."userID" = '6F9BD058-853F-4B50-92D6-9170118A2727' 
            THEN TRUE 
            ELSE FALSE 
            END as "onWatchlist",
       CASE WHEN "userWatched"."userID" = '6F9BD058-853F-4B50-92D6-9170118A2727' AND "userWatched"."watchedDate" IS NOT NULL 
            THEN TRUE 
            ELSE FALSE 
            END as "watched",
            count(DISTINCT "overallWatched"."watchedDate") as "viewCount" 
FROM "Movie" 
LEFT JOIN "Series" ON "Series"."id" = "Movie"."seriesID" 
LEFT JOIN "Author" ON "Author"."id" = "Movie"."authorID" 
LEFT JOIN "UserMovieFavourited" ON "UserMovieFavourited"."movieID" = "Movie"."id" 
                                AND "UserMovieFavourited"."userID" = '6F9BD058-853F-4B50-92D6-9170118A2727' 
LEFT JOIN "UserMovieWatchlist" ON "UserMovieWatchlist"."movieID" = "Movie"."id" 
                               AND "UserMovieWatchlist"."userID" = '6F9BD058-853F-4B50-92D6-9170118A2727' 
LEFT JOIN "UserMovieWatchProgress" as "userWatched" ON "userWatched"."movieID" = "Movie"."id" 
                                                    AND "userWatched"."userID" = '6F9BD058-853F-4B50-92D6-9170118A2727' 
LEFT JOIN "UserMovieWatchProgress" as "overallWatched" ON "overallWatched"."movieID" = "Movie"."id" 
GROUP BY "Movie"."id", 
         "Author"."photoURL", 
         "Author"."name", 
         "Author"."surname", 
         "Series"."name", 
         "Series"."logoURL", 
         "userWatched"."watchedDate", 
         "UserMovieFavourited"."userID", 
         "UserMovieWatchlist"."userID", 
         "userWatched"."userID"
```

In MySQL i needed only one column for grouping that's Movie.id. For postgresql I needed to add 10 columns to make this query work as shown above.

Is this natural for postgresql or this query should be refactored to remove need of so many grouping columns?

Comment: MySQL query which group only my `Movie.id` will not run in any other dbms because it doesn't make sense.  This is the correct way.  One improvement you can make is to only join the necessary tables in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_name

Comment: This quotes are generated by swifQL plain query export.

Comment: All *.id in this query are primary keys for all columns

Comment: @Eric I was adding columns to group by one by one until query was executed and this is the result which I really not feel should look like. But maybe I am wrong so I asked this question

Comment: *In MySQL i needed only one column for grouping that's Movie.id.* This is MySQL extension. And use this is a bad pactice - even in MySQL. Don't try to save bytes...

Comment: @Akina so I switched to postgresql to make it better. So question is: Is my query properly valid as a good practice or should be fixed somehow. As it executes and returns required data.

Comment: I do not see the next fields in GROUP BY expression: "Movie"."title","Movie"."publicationDate","Movie"."authorID","Movie"."seriesID","Movie"."languageID" as "language","Movie"."ratingUp","Movie"."ratingDown". Of course they are masked by "Movie"."id", but...

Comment: @Akina I didn't added them as I was adding the only one that postgresql was dropping me an error as missing

Comment: In Postgres `CASE WHEN "field" = 'value' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END` may be replaced with simple `"field" = 'value'`... see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b94e39a5bc87224cf394d16d9fc10cc).

Comment: "*Is this natural for postgresql*" - yes, and for every other self respecting DBMS that cares for correct resulst

Answer (score 0):

Imagine there is a row in `"Movie"` where `id` is 42.

Then imagine that there are two rows in `"UserMovieWatchProgress"` where `"movieID"` is 42.

Then the result of

```
"Movie" LEFT JOIN "UserMovieWatchProgress"
   ON "UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID" = "Movie"."id"
```

would be something like

```
 "Movie".id | "UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID"
------------+------------------------------------
         42 |                                143
         42 |                                 93
```

Now consider the following query:

```
SELECT "Movie".id,
       "UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID"
FROM "Movie"
   LEFT JOIN "UserMovieWatchProgress"
      ON "UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID" = "Movie"."id"
GROUP BY "Movie".id;
```

By definition of `GROUP BY`, there can be only one result row per `"Movie".id`.
Which number should we take for `"UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID"`? That is unclear and not well defined, so this is forbidden by the SQL standard.

Now if PostgreSQL can deduce that there can be only one possible `"UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID"`, it will allow you to omit the column from the `GROUP BY` clause.

---

If you just want any of the `"UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID"` in the query result, and you don't care which one, you can do the following in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Movie".id)
       "Movie".id,
       "UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID"
FROM "Movie"
   LEFT JOIN "UserMovieWatchProgress"
      ON "UserMovieWatchProgress"."movieID" = "Movie"."id";
```

Perhaps that is what you are looking for.

Comment: There are two cases for this table. One I need to know if user watched movie. And second one how many times users overall watched movie so which user it does not matter that is why I needed to make this aliased same table twice to get this data

Comment: You *do* care about individual users, else you wouldn't have `"userWatched"."userID"` in the `SELECT` list outside an aggregate function.

Comment: userWatched is first case when it matters. overallWatched is the case when it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, just add all columns that appear outside of aggregates to the `GROUP BY` clause and be done with it. I don't see the big problem.

Comment: I was using MySQL for many years for some easy hobby projects and now I decided to switch and I looked weird to me. But as I read above its normal I will be ok with such postgresql behavior and learn how it looks here. Thank you for explanations

Comment: @akina one more about this if I add to joined columns "and movie.id = [myid]" to narrow join results then the group by for such table column could be ommited? For example on first 2 joined tables?